# Как правильно передать массив в _stprintf_s()?

Tags: c++, массивы, winapi, функции

Почему в функцию передаётся `TCHAR(&name)[100]`, а не `TCHAR *name`?

```
void CreateName(TCHAR(&name)[100], int number)
{
    _stprintf_s(name, TEXT("Your number: %d"), number);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации Майкрософт функция `_stprintf_s` является макроопределением следующего вида

```
#define _stprintf_s swprintf_s
```

В свою очередь функция `swprintf_s` определяется как

```
template <size_t size>  
int swprintf_s(  
   wchar_t (&buffer)[size],  
   const wchar_t *format,  
   ...  
); // C++ only
```

То есть это шаблонная функция шаблонным параметром которой является размер массива. Поэтому массив, используемый в качестве аргумента передается функции по ссылке, чтобы функция могла определить размер массива.

Соответственно и функция `CreateName` объявляется свой первый параметр как ссылку на массив, который она далее передает в функцию `_stprintf_s`. Если бы она не принимала массив по ссылке, то не смогла бы вызвать функцию `_stprintf_s`.

Для вызова функции `CreateName` нужно просто указать имя массива в качестве аргумента, как это делает в свою очередь сама функция при вызове функции `_stprintf_s`.